# Get first eight bytes of a MD5 string

Tags: php

I want to get the first eight bytes of a calculated MD5 string. In Ruby I do this:

```
Digest::MD5.digest("foo")[0, 8]
```

What is the best way to do this in PHP?

EDIT: I don't want it as a String, which `substr()` returns. I thought of calling `md5("foo", true)`, where the true parameter enables returning binary. I want to cut the 16 bytes to 8 bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I remember correctly, using [`md5()`](http://php.net/md5) and [`hex2bin()`](http://php.net/hex2bin) should do what you want:

```
substr(hex2bin(md5("foo")), 0, 8);
```

EDIT:

If the `hex2bin()` function is not defined, you can alternatively implement it yourself using this function (from [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php#31107)):

```
function hex2bin($hexdata) { 
  $bindata=""; 

  for ($i=0;$i<strlen($hexdata);$i+=2) { 
    $bindata.=chr(hexdec(substr($hexdata,$i,2))); 
  } 

  return $bindata; 
}
```

Comment: Only in SVN. :( Will also give back 16 byte. I could call md5() with true as second parameter to get the same. My problem is how to cut the 16 byte to 8 byte.

Comment: @Lennart Well, then you should be able to just use `substr(md5("foo", true), 0, 8)`, right?

Comment: substr() seems to always return a String. :(

Comment: @Lennart So does `md5("", true)`, but that is because a string does not necessarily represent just text, it can be binary data too. What other data type do you expect it would be?

Comment: Okay I just tried it out - It actually works! I guess I have to find out more about the PHP return types and stuff. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Lennart if you need an integer, you can do this: `$x = (int) substr(md5("foo", true), 0, 8)`

Answer (score 3):

Use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

`substr(md5("foo"),0,8);`

Comment: That gives back a String! I need it as in Ruby: irb(main):002:0> Digest::MD5.digest("foo")[0, 8]
=> "\254\275\030\333L\302\370\\"

Answer (score 0):

Use `md5` and `substr`: `substr(md5("foo"), 0, 8)`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to do:

```
printf(substr(md5('foo'),0,8));
```